# Are there any examples of #! indexed websites on the internet?

Tags: search-engine-indexing

It seems that although google say they can index Ajax websites I cannot find any websites where this currently works. Does anyone know of any sites that are indexed?

Comment: This site http://imagemechanics.com.au/ appears to have a few `#!` URLs indexed, although none of the `/blog/` section appears to be indexed which I think is down to an incorrectly implemented `?_escaped_fragment_=/blog/...` URL (required by Google) which results in a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also been looking and the answer is no, I can't find any or many.

I think this by itself is something you need to consider. Google doesn't use this, and you can't find any one who does.

Now, should a technology or SEO dictate your approach. YES! You don't have to use #! to use Ajax there are other ways - I've just spoken to our Ajax / JQuery experts here and only one of them have even heard of this (#!) and said don't touch it.

Don't get me wrong, I know Google [suggest to use it](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq) for Ajax, but from my research (and yours) I think you've answered your own question here!

I know this isn't a direct answer but I hope is useful.

Comment: From your [link](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq), Google suggests searching for `https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq` - this does at least bring up a few `#!` indexed pages.

Comment: Thanks, this was a very helpful answer. I don't know why the question was closed.